# C#, PostgreSQL syntax error at end of input

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-7.0, postgresql-15

I can't seem to be able to create migration with simplest sql to create PostgreSQL procedure.

Error is:

> Exception data:
> Severity: ERROR
> SqlState: 42601
> MessageText: syntax error at end of input
> Position: 186
> File: scan.l
> Line: 1184
> Routine: scanner_yyerror

Sql code works fine when executed in pgAdmin.

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE reset_primary_holder()
                LANGUAGE SQL
                BEGIN ATOMIC

                SELECT * FROM id.users;

                END;";
    migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
}

What am I doing wrong?
```

Comment: A procedure isn't meant to return a result you need to use a function. (Btw: do you really have a schema named `id`? Sounds like  a strange naming convention)

Comment: I guess EF parses the SQL string somehow and stops at the first `;` and thus sends a partial (and invalid) SQL command to the server

Comment: You are right, but how to modify sql to have only one `;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end only viable solution was to to use different syntax:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure()
            AS $$
            UPDATE id.users
            SET ...;
            Another statement;
            $$ LANGUAGE sql;";            
    migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
}
```

This syntax is not mentioned in documentation on stored procedures and since this is my first PG procedure / function it was not immediately obvious to me that there is alternative.

Thanks @Shay for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Npgsql (the ADO.NET driver, not the EF provider) by default parses SQL to find semicolons and rewrite statements, and the new PostgreSQL syntax breaks that parser; see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4445.

The general recommended fix is to add the following to the start of your program:

```cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableSqlRewriting", false);
```

This disables statement parsing/rewriting altogether; it means you need to use positional parameter placeholders (`$1`, `$2` instead of `@p1`, `@p2`) - see [the docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/6.0.html#raw-sql-mode-and-new-batching-api).

However, EF is unfortunately not yet compatible with this mode, so you'll have to make do without this syntax...

Comment: Thanks @Shay. If I understand correctly problem is with new syntax that PG introduced. Is there a way to rewrite this code without BEGIN ATOMIC or to set the switch back on after migrations are run at startup? I know that this is not the question might not be for for you, but I have to try :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the same thing can be done in PG with another syntax - that's more a question for PG people. Unfortunately, Npgsql caches the value of EnableSqlRewriting (for perf), so you can't change it after startup.

Comment: But note that EF generally discourages running migrations at startup ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)). If you run migrations separately, it's easy to work around this by setting EnableSqlRewriting to false only for migrations (via a design-time context), or by executing SQL migrations scripts directly (at which point Npgsql isn't involved).

Comment: Thanks @Shay, I really appreciate your help here and in general your contributions to community.